# Work out which regions are missing - mapping in ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, missing-data

I am using ggplot2 to map some data onto the UK based on parliamentary constituencies. There are 650 constituencies in the UK, but only 634 in my dataframe.

I want to identify which ones are missing, so I can work out whether that is because there's been an error in my work, or because those 16 legitimately aren't relevant so don't have any data to report. How do I do this? I've used...

```
identical(df$Parliamentary.Constituency.Name, mapfile$Parliamentary.Constituency.Name)
```

Unsurprisingly, this tells me that it's not identical, but no further info.

As a secondary concern, if the latter (or if the error is somehow insurmountable), I want the constituencies to be grayed out on the map.

In terms of colouration, this is my simplified code for the map:

```
ggplot()  +
  geom_map(data = df, 
           aes(map_id = df$Parliamentary.Constituency.Name, 
               fill = df$Data.of.interest), 
           map = mapfile) +
  geom_polygon (data = mapfile, 
                aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), 
                colour = NA, fill = NA) +
  expand_limits(x = mapfile$long, y = mapfile$lat) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(guide = "colourbar", low = ("green4"), mid = ("white"), 
                       high = ("red"), midpoint = 0, na.value = "darkgray")  +
  coord_equal ())
```

As you can see, I currently have na.value as dark gray, but there are no dark grays on the map when I run it.

EDIT: I have worked out which regions are missing using the following code, but I still don't know how to make them gray out on the map. To confirm, they're missing because there's no relevant data to map.

```
setdiff(mapfile$Parliamentary.Constituency.Name, df$Parliamentary.Constituency.Name)
```

Comment: You need to expand the data frame with the variable mapped to `fill` to include the missing levels. Switching to [sf](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/) will make this a little less confusing.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?